# Experimentally found weird number theory pattern $p^\frac{d-3}{2}\cdot \left(p^\frac{d-1}2 \pm \{-1 \text{ or } p-1 \}\right) \mod d$ equals $0,1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

In the course of studying a problem involving counting points on hyperspheres and hyperplanes in dimension $d$ mod $p$, I came across the following interesting pattern

> **Conjecture/Question**: for (odd?) primes $p,d$, for some choice of sign $(\text{sgn}_p^d) \in \{+1, -1\}$,
> $$p^\frac{d-3}{2}\cdot \Bigg(p^\frac{d-1}2 + (\text{sgn}_p^d) \cdot \begin{cases} -1 \\ p-1 \end{cases}  \Bigg) \mod d$$
> gives the values $0,1$ in some order (meaning one of the two branches in the 'cases environment' is $0$ and the other is $1$). Which sign is it, and which branch of the 'cases environment' give $0$ and which gives $1$? (So the **conjecture** is "there exists a sign s.t. ..." and the **question** is asking "which sign, and which branch ...")

For example, for $p=13,d=19$, the sign is $\text{sgn}_p^d = -1$, and indeed using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=13%5E8%20*%20%2813%5E9-1%29%20mod%2019) one checks that the top branch gives $0$ and the bottom branch gives $1$. If on the other hand we try the sign $= +1$, the top branch gives $6$ and the bottom branch gives $5$.

---

Here's another phrasing of the above due to user @[cnikbesku](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/992037/cnikbesku) that is a bit more rigorous and may make a bit more sense:

> **Conjecture/Question**: There exists a function $s:P^2\rightarrow\{-1,1\}$, where $P$ stands for the set of all (maybe odd) prime numbers, such that for all $(p,d)\in P^2$ we have:
> $$\bigg(p^\frac{d-3}{2}\Big(p^\frac{d-1}2-s(p,d)\Big)\;\text{mod}\;d,\;\;p^\frac{d-3}{2}\Big(p^\frac{d-1}2+s(p,d)\cdot(p-1)\Big)\;\text{mod}\;d\bigg)\in\{(0,1),(1,0)\}.$$
> The question is what can we say about whether is it $(0,1)$ or $(1,0)$ for such function $s$?

For example, for $p=13,d=19$, the only possible value for $s(p,d)$ is $-1$, and indeed using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=13%5E8%20*%20%2813%5E9-1%29%20mod%2019) one checks that the pair is $(0,1)$. If on the other hand we try $s(p,d)=1$, the pair becomes $(6,5)$.

---

Besides isolating the above conjecture/questions, I don't really have any further work/guesses (perhaps Euler's criterion may be helpful, reducing to some Legendre symbols) but I hope that the puzzle itself is interesting enough to warrant staying open.

Comment: what is $(\text{sgn}_p^d) \; \; ? \; \;$

Comment: @WillJagy I'm defining $(\text{sgn}_p^d)$ to be the "some choice of sign in the $\pm$" that satisfies the conjecture (evaluates to $0$ or $1$). That is why I used the "define equals" notation $=:$. Because it seems to confuse a lot of people I rewrote it.

Comment: @user originally the RHS was supposed to be an alternative notation for the LHS (hence the "define equals" notation $=:$). It was confusing so I fixed it. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: I tried to edit your question so that it is more clear. Can you try to approve it?

Comment: As you guessed, it is an immediate consequence of **Euler's Criterion** (and a simple case analysis). Why didn't you try working out the details?

Comment: @BillDubuque good question. Now that I see it is simple, but where the problem came from I suppose I believed that the sign question would be very difficult (Gauss famously struggled with the sign of the Gauss sum for years https://mattbaker.blog/2015/04/30/the-sign-of-the-quadratic-gauss-sum-and-quadratic-reciprocity/, and I thought that this would be similar). I had not noticed the pattern in the computer simulations, and I guess the $p^\frac{d-3}2$ and the $\pm 1$ factors threw me off (because those don't immediately look nice mod $d$). So a mental block due to the presumed difficulty.

Comment: @cnikbesku 2 reviewers rejected your edit because "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner." Indeed one of my questions is "what is the function $s(p,d)$?" and that doesn't appear in your edit. I also feel that it is also a bit more difficult to parse than my own phrasing (of course I am biased). However, I do appreciate your work and I think it's good to be able to see both phrasings, so I put it there alongside my own phrasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conjecture follows from the Euler's criterion: If $p$ is a prime and $(a,p) = 1$, then $$a^{\tfrac{p-1}{2}}\equiv 
\begin{cases}
1 \pmod p&\text{if $a$ is a quadratic residue $\bmod p$}\\
-1 \pmod p&\text{if $a$ is a non-quadratic residue $\bmod p$}
\end{cases}$$

Also, observe that $a^{\tfrac{p-3}{2}} a = a^{\tfrac{p-1}{2}}\equiv \pm1\pmod p$, so $a^{\tfrac{p-3}{2}}\equiv\pm a^{-1} \pmod p$ where $a^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $a$ $\bmod p$.

In your case, if $p$ and $d$ are two distinct primes we have two cases:

- $p$ is a quadratic residue $\bmod d$

Then
$$p^\frac{d-3}{2} \left(p^\frac{d-1}2 + \begin{cases} -1 \\ p-1 \end{cases}\right) \equiv p^{-1}\left(1+\begin{cases} -1 \\ p-1 \end{cases}\right) = \begin{cases} 0 \\ p^{-1}p\end{cases}\equiv \begin{cases} 0 \\ 1\end{cases}\pmod d$$

- $p$ is a non-quadraric residue $\bmod d$

Then $$p^\frac{d-3}{2} \left(p^\frac{d-1}2 - \begin{cases} -1 \\ p-1 \end{cases}\right) \equiv -p^{-1}\left(-1-\begin{cases} -1 \\ p-1 \end{cases}\right) = \begin{cases} 0 \\ (-p^{-1})(-p)\end{cases}\equiv \begin{cases} 0 \\ 1\end{cases}\pmod d$$

Answer (score 1):

Using commas for an ordered list   and $(p|q)$ for Legendre symbol. After multiplying through by $p$  I get the question to be
$$  1 + (p|q) (p-1, -1, 1-p,1  )  \equiv \; \; (?,?,?,?)   \pmod d   $$

If $(p|d) = 1$  the first pair $(p-1,-1)$  is mapped to $(p,0)$  while the second pair is mapped to $(2-p,2)$  and these are reduced $\pmod d$  The part about $(1,0)$ came up because you divided by $p.$

Similar if $(p|d) = -1$   and the second pair works.